# Writing to the OutputStream of Java Process/ProcessBuilder as pipe

Tags: java, process, outputstream, processbuilder

I have problems sending data from java to a (linux)-subprocess created by **ProcessBuilder/Process**.

A shell-only based basic example would look like as follows and works fine.

```
echo "hello world" | cat - >/tmp/receive.dat
```

Now, I want to substituted the `echo "hello world"` by a java program which should internally create a new process (the `cat - >/tmp/receive.dat`) and then send data to it.

I tried the following, but the file `/tmp/receive.dat` remains untouched:

```
String[] cmdArray = { "/bin/cat", "-", ">/tmp/receive.dat" };
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder (cmdArray);
builder.directory (new File ("/tmp"));
Process p = builder.start ();
OutputStream pos = p.getOutputStream ();

byte [] bytes = "hello world".getBytes ();
pos.write (bytes);
pos.close ();
p.waitFor ();
```

The same happens under Windows, of course with an adapted cmdArray:

```
cmd /c type con >c:\tmp\receive.dat
```

Printing directly to system.out from java is no alternative as many subprocesses should be called within the livecycle of the java program.

thx for any help!
Tombo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that `/bin/cat` does not actually write to files, it merely writes to standard out. The output redirection `>/tmp/receive.dat` is actually performed by the shell, but you are bypassing the shell by invoking `cat` in this manner.

If what you are trying to achieve is merely an OutputStream that writes to a file, then doing that via standard java I/O (e.g., FileOutputStream and friends) is what you want. It is also cross-platform (i.e., Windows-friendly), unlike anything that depends on the shell.

Regarding the comment about not being able to merely write to standard out from java because of subprocesses - any subprocess you invoke can inherit standard out from their parent process (the java process - look at `ProcessBuilder.Redirect.INHERIT`). So even if you are invoking subprocesses from java, redirecting all the output to a file should still work in the same way as your initial example (where the java program replaces the echo command).

Comment: weird! of course, the output redirection is done by the shell but we do not have any shell here, so >/tmp/receive.dat was sent to cat as parameter  ... I tested it with another receiver-command (ghostscript) it works fine!

Comment: There may be some special logic within ghostscript itself which interprets ">file" to mean "write to file", but cat has no such functionality (it always simply writes to standard out). I spent a minute looking for a command that was the inverse of cat (writes standard input to a file named as a parameter) but didn't see such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want [ProcessBuilder#redirectOutput(File)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectOutput-java.io.File-), as the > functionality is not of cat, rather what is calling cat (in our sense, the process builder).

Comment: It is a functionof the command shell. Nothing to do wih either `cat` or the process builder.