# Is there a way to save the obtained output from a a process object's getOutPutStream() method into a file

Tags: java, process, fileoutputstream

Coming from this link "[Writing to the OutputStream of Java Process/ProcessBuilder as pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38547393/writing-to-the-outputstream-of-java-process-processbuilder-as-pipe)" and researching i didn't find a way to specify a path for writing a process output from getOutputStream().

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("commands.txt")));
        String[] input = br.readLine().split(" ");

        String cmd =  input[0] + " " + input[1] + " " + input[3];

        System.out.println(cmd);

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c", cmd});


        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

        OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(input[3]));

        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len;

        while ( (len = in.read()) > 0) {
            // out.write();
        }
```

In the code the exec run a process that concatenate the results from a two files and now i want to save the result in a new file. But i cannot find how because the getOutPutStream object from process have only one method write with constructor that takes int[] as parameter. Thank you for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `InputStream` and `OutputStream` in this scenario. Consider them as input/output to your code. Of what I understand, you want to take what's in your `in` reader and output it to `out`. I don't see why you'd need to use the `getOutputStream` of `Process`.

Since Java 9, there is a very simple solution for this, namely the `transferTo` method of `Reader`. In effect, you could replace everything after your `Process` initialization with the following:

`process.getInputStream().transferTo(new FileOutputStream(input[3]))`

Comment: You was right i mismatch the Input and Output Streams. Thank you !